# Conditional Fields module with Google Maps

Tags: 7, javascript, google-maps, entities

I'm trying to initially hide a geofield created with [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) module using [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) that uses the [Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation) Google Maps Input Widget.

If I click on one of my conditional fields to show the Google Map Input Widget, it shows the Google Map Input with a grey background.  If you resize the browser, the map tiles show again.

Does anyone know of a way to hook into the javascript somehow to reinitialize the Google Map when it is shown?

Answer (score 0):

I added a possible solution at https://www.drupal.org/node/1277888#comment-11680473.  Hope that helps someone.